# How Do I create a SQL-like query with Angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the json file below. I will like to use Angularjs ng-repeat to display some data if, for example, the value of the  field ‘productTypeNumber’ equals “CREDITS” .

In SQL, you could create a query like ‘ select * from somewhere WHERE something=‘aValue’

I have already tried “ng-repeat ‘item in items” but I don’t know how to go further to do the filtering.

```
{ "productOverviewInfo" : [ { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "Credits 1"
      },
    "agreementNumber" : { "E" : "7i1li8HKJXPsuua3wVjRIGCDKF0eW4QEojlrmy3qfYI=",
        "T" : "hidden"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "+FxW+sUWZhz2COHKUKeUfzYdsGZHcC3SjtM1H/nK/6E=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "1"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "CREDITS"
      }
  },
  { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "Loan Balance Insurance 1"
      },
    "agreementNumber" : { "E" : "ikUA/JZIenm8CH3Yqg1fGPGUC823misEI/leUq5WRu8=",
        "T" : "hidden"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "RuwzO2T3Ckx/dJAtrx8oZ32MueyWztcBIM7BLCyXoRg=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "1"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "LOANBALANCEINS"
      }
  },
  { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "House Insurance 1"
      },
    "agreementNumber" : { "E" : "ZYiaaho+tH5l6j7rYZIizWisEu7/9zLMG/n+MYtyvN8=",
        "T" : "hidden"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "0tgAy2IQ2TnhVHA49R282DNTqS5dcaEVsiYZBk7Aqvw=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "1"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "HOUSEINS"
      }
  },
  { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "Credits 2"
      },
    "agreementNumber" : { "E" : "Jb7EK6h+kh+SqK4Z2BDJ/XHl04mwCN71bI/AcWuqtrE=",
        "T" : "hidden"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "SziYFGSXHzE6kwaw5fwmh0hbz5hAui6ZTO7HtvKUGIU=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "2"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "CREDITS"
      }
  },
  { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "Loan Balance Insurance 2"
      },
    "agreementNumber" : { "E" : "NrYKr+PY/6Uz5SXcfMFbs7JxP3w34O9LhQ3/wvvm9rA=",
        "T" : "hidden"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "hrYVzn4TrTURGbkVo+VG4tSdqo88l65NbMnvPY3aFTc=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "2"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "LOANBALANCEINS"
      }
  },
  { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "987654306"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "D1aSlOOBIsMlshehl4v4aJBiGWZb1Fp4/45wSLikKG4=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "2"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "House Insurance 2"
      }
  },
  { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "Credits 3"
      },
    "agreementNumber" : { "E" : "Lw+HmRbP3nP7h+Lx3rfN+FkL5J+qNXy/+jPwARwV4uY=",
        "T" : "hidden"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "FOYM9Yw1HIBFyGNshOail0zDmjwtsrc6VX0al08QcRQ=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "3"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "CREDITS"
      }
  },
  { "agreementName" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "Credits 4"
      },
    "agreementNumber" : { "E" : "857F3N+oA+/XoDaF8une5ujY130irRSw9Jf1mz2odMc=",
        "T" : "hidden"
      },
    "groupNumber" : { "E" : "Ovad7odXFlAPC6j9MH0lV2y/XbUX46jPu5Of7GlEDqw=",
        "T" : "text",
        "V" : "1001"
      },
    "order" : { "T" : "short",
        "V" : "4"
      },
    "productTypeNumber" : { "T" : "text",
        "V" : "CREDITS"
      }
  }
] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ng-repeat="info in productOverviewInfo | filter:{productTypeNumber.V: "CREDITS"}
```

I haven't tested it - not sure if it works.

Comment: I have tried the above but it's not doing the filtering. I still have ALL the data being displayed.

Comment: I missed the "V" member, try it again?

Comment: .car(ng-repeat="info in productOverviewList | filter:{productTypeNumber.V:"CREDITS"} ")   This is throwing compilation error:"Unexpected token name «CREDITS», expected punc «)» (line: 51, col: 105, pos: 2958)". When I took off the qoutation off, the jade compiles but the filtering doesn't work yet.